# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: _SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_AppUtil

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, clang, analytics

ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/ahmed/Documents/C1/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_AppUtil", referenced from:
_SWIGExceptionHelper_SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_AppUtil_mAD2F9A77CA68FFB83FABFC579B2D13DE235E02E3 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o
(maybe you meant: _SWIGExceptionHelper_SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_AppUtil_mAD2F9A77CA68FFB83FABFC579B2D13DE235E02E3)
"_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_DefaultName_get", referenced from:
_AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_DefaultName_get_m4A778152B530BD60EA311A032035B8EE0B88F693 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o
_FirebaseApp_get_DefaultName_mBA7DA11C2791078BAA59206A945890E958546168 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o
(maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_DefaultName_get_m4A778152B530BD60EA311A032035B8EE0B88F693)
"_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_0", referenced from:

....

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Unity SDK on iOS can be conceptualized as three distinct components:

1. the iOS SDK (what is included with the `Podfile`).
2. the C++ SDK. This is a cross platform layer that can be backed by the iOS or Android SDKs on those respective platforms and provides rudimentary desktop support on Windows, MacOS, and Linux.
3. a C#/Unity SDK that binds to the C++ SDK with the Mono P/Invoke system.

Since I see that you have your workspace open, that the `Pods` project is installed, and that all your exceptions are linker errors referencing [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) generated functions (the core of the C#/C++ boundary layer), I'm going to assume that the `.a` files you need for part 2 are missing or not linked.

So, first check that you have `libFirebaseCpp*.cpp` files for each plugin included in your project:
[image: Screenshot of Assets/Plugins/iOS/Firebase in the Unity library view]

Note that these are included in the `.unitypkg` files rather than downloaded via a process like EDM4U. So when you're upgrading (or installing) be sure to include them:
[image: Screenshot of the "Import Unity Package" window for FirebaseAuth. Pointing to libFirebaseCppApp.a and libFirebaseCppAuth.a at the bottom]

Common reasons that these files aren't included in your Unity project are:

1. developers overaggressively auditing the Firebase `unitypkg` files
2. version control systems doing a blanket ignore of any files ending in `.a` to avoid uploading build artifacts (static libraries in this case).

Finally, if you see the necessary `.a` files included but you're still getting an issue, you should ensure that they're included in the iOS build. You can do this by checking the inspector for this library:
[image: Screenshot showing the inspector open for libFirebaseCppApp.a. An arrow points to "iOS" being checked for "Select platforms for plugin"]

And making sure that you're including the related `.meta` file in your project and `platformData:` has an entry for `iPhone: iOS` set to `enabled: 1`. My own `.meta` file looks like this, but it can vary based on Unity Editor version and the order you check elements in the inspector, so you probably shouldn't copy/paste this:
`libFirebaseCppApp.a.meta`

```
fileFormatVersion: 2
guid: 601e8e1d2d2744929ede33676cbeccc0
labels:
- gvh
- gvh_version-6.1.1
PluginImporter:
  externalObjects: {}
  serializedVersion: 2
  iconMap: {}
  executionOrder: {}
  defineConstraints: []
  isPreloaded: 0
  isOverridable: 0
  isExplicitlyReferenced: 0
  validateReferences: 1
  platformData:
  - first:
      Any: 
    second:
      enabled: 0
      settings: {}
  - first:
      Editor: Editor
    second:
      enabled: 0
      settings:
        DefaultValueInitialized: true
  - first:
      iPhone: iOS
    second:
      enabled: 1
      settings:
        AddToEmbeddedBinaries: false
  userData: 
  assetBundleName: 
  assetBundleVariant:
```